# Probability with Random.Next()

Tags: c#, random

I want to write a lottery draw program which needs to randomly choose 20000 numbers from 1-2000000 range. The code is as below:

```
Random r = New Random(seed); //seed is a 6 digits e.g 123456
int i=0;
while(true){
   r.Next(2000000);
   i++;
   if(i>=20000)
      break;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Can it make sure the same possibility of all the numbers from 1 to 2000000?
2. Is the upper bound 2000000 included in the `r.Next()`?
3. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Liath Because he wants 20000 random numbers, not one random integer between 20000 and 2000000?

Comment: What does the documentation for `Random.Next(int)` tell you in terms of the upper bound? (It doesn't mention the distribution - which will be uniform in theory, but is probably not as uniform as it *could* be.)

Comment: Do you want distinct numbers? Or are duplicate numbers acceptable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET Random class does a fairly good job of generating random numbers. However be aware that if you seed it with the same number you'll get the same "random" numbers each time. If you don't want this behavior don't provide a seed.

If you're after much more random number generator than the built in .NET one then take a look at [random.org](http://www.random.org/). It's one of the best sites out there for getting true random numbers - I believe there's an API. Here's a quote from their site:

> RANDOM.ORG offers true random numbers to anyone on the Internet. The
>   randomness comes from atmospheric noise, which for many purposes is
>   better than the pseudo-random number algorithms typically used in
>   computer programs. People use RANDOM.ORG for holding drawings,
>   lotteries and sweepstakes, to drive games and gambling sites, for
>   scientific applications and for art and music. The service has existed
>   since 1998 and was built by Dr Mads Haahr of the School of Computer
>   Science and Statistics at Trinity College, Dublin in Ireland. Today,
>   RANDOM.ORG is operated by Randomness and Integrity Services Ltd.

Finally Random.Next() is [exlusive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so the upper value you supply will never be called. You may need to adjust your code appropriately if you want 2000000 to be in there.

Comment: no, that is not true, there are no true random numbers, many random systems are based for example on the systems timestamp and stuff like that. Computers can not generate any random stuff! you are able to calculate anything. Sure some methods seem to be more random or harder to re-calculate, but any system needs a start value, after which you can calculate the output

Comment: @FelixLahmer which bit specifically do you think I've got wrong? I agree there are no true random, however the site I recommended I believe uses weather which is one of the best mechanisms surely?

Comment: @FelixLahmer: Did you read the web site Liath linked to? Note that there are hardware modules available using radioactive decay etc. As far as I'm aware, radioactive decay is still thought to be random - or at the very least, not predictable by humans. Just because *many* systems use timestamps doesn't mean that's all that's available.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to explain why I recommend random.org for business critical randomness.

Comment: I can't think of a question where random.org is the answer. I'd go with `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` for important things. If it's not secure, you can't obtain random data from random.org securely either. In general, you pretty much rely on `/dev/urandom` or `CryptGenRandom` working.

Comment: @JonSkeet indeed, i know that site, and 2 weeks ago i was totally with you, till i talked with a prof, which told me: Just because we do not know how to calculate these values, they are not TRUELY random, they just seem random to us. But yeah i think you can discuss pretty extensive about that topic ;)

Comment: @FelixLahmer interesting, thanks. I'd still suggest it's the best we've got through but it's certainly interesting!

Comment: Actually there are some True random generators, they do provide numbers based on cosmic background noise coming from space, I guess this is really as random as it can be :D but these services are not free

Comment: @aybe and in 200000 years you even will be able to calculate that

Comment: @FelixLahmer: Not knowing how to calculate the values doesn't make it random - but it doesn't make it *not* random either. Is there evidence that radioactive decay is *not* random? (And of course for *practical* purposes, thorough unpredictability is almost always going to be good enough.)

Comment: @JonSkeet as far as i know, there are calculations to delimit, which may allows an elimination process, but i am not  in that materia in any way and i cant quote from official documents/books

Answer (score 2):

It includes the *minValue* but does not include the *maxValue*. Therefore if you want to generate numbers from 1 to 2000000 use:

```
r.Next(1,2000001)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is implementation dependent.

The naïve method of generating a random integer in a range is to generate a random 32-bit word and then normalise it across your range.

The larger the range you're normalising the more the probabilities of each individual value fluctuate.

In your situation, you're normalising 4.3 billion inputs over 2 million outputs. This will mean that the probabilities of each number in your range will differ by up to about 1 in 2000 (or 0.05%). If this slight difference in probabilities is okay for you, then go ahead.

Comment: Also, bear in mind the fact that your 6-digit seed means you only have between 19 and 20 bits of entropy in your entire system.

Comment: why the inputs are 4.3 billion. How do you get that value?

Comment: 32-bit integer gives 2^32 different values (about 4.3 billion).

Comment: But how about the probability to get each number of 20000 number from within that 2 million range? why we should consider the 32bit integer value as the base is only 1 to 2 million?

Comment: I spoke about a naïve algorithm for generating a random integer in a range by normalising a random 32-bit integer. I have no idea how .Net actually handles `r.Next()` and will assume it's implementation dependent.

Answer (score 0):

- Upperbound included?

No, the upperbound is *exclusive* so you'll have to use 2000001 to include 2000000.

- Any suggestion?

Let me take the liberty of suggesting not to use a `while(true) / break`. Simply put the condition of the if in your while statement:

```
Random r = New Random(seed); //seed is a 6 digits e.g 123456
int i=0;

while(i++ < 20000)
{
    r.Next(1, 2000001);
}
```

I know this is nitpicking, but it **is** a suggestion... :)

Comment: What's wrong with `for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++) { ... }`?

Comment: Nothing, why would there be? I was only suggesting *not* to use `while(true)/break`. If he wants to use a for-loop, that's also fine.

Comment: Sorry, it's just the original question and your fix seemed to go out of the way to avoid using the obvious `for` loop.